# "object not found" when using .SD and expression in .by together

Tags: r, data.table

this problem drives me crazy:

first let's say we have this example dataset:

```
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(mydate = seq(as.Date("2009-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), by = "day"),
                 id = sample(1:5, 1096, replace = T),
                 id.sub = sample(letters[1:3], 1096, replace = T),
                 val = rnorm(1096))
```

it looks like this:

```
           mydate id id.sub        val
   1: 2009-01-01  4      c -0.2712793
   2: 2009-01-02  5      b  1.8967819
   3: 2009-01-03  3      b  1.0168226
   4: 2009-01-04  5      a  0.8324829
   5: 2009-01-05  1      a -1.8251198
  ---                                
1092: 2011-12-28  4      c -1.2794301
1093: 2011-12-29  2      a  0.1221805
1094: 2011-12-30  2      c -1.2370464
1095: 2011-12-31  3      c  2.2440864
1096: 2012-01-01  2      a  1.1407802
```

now i want to compute the maximum of date and the mean of val if id.sub equals to "b", by each id and each week. here's how far i got:

```
dt[,
   .(max.date = max(mydate),
     mean.val = mean(.SD[id.sub == "b", val])),
   by = list(id, wk = format(mydate, "%Y-%V"))]
```

however, the following error keeps me beating my head against the wall:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(max.date = max(mydate, na.rm = T), mean = sum(.SD[id.sub ==  : 

  object 'mydate' not found
```

if i remove either the "mean.val" line or "max.date" line, the code works, but it just cannot run correctly when they're put together. i have no idea how it go wrong, can anyone help me? many thanks.

my data.table version is v1.9.5

Comment: Did you maybe intend to write `mean.val = mean(val[id.sub == "b"])`?

Comment: The right way to do is what RichardScriven mentioned, But, if you want to use your code, create a new column 'wk' first, i.e. `dt[,wk:=format(mydate, '%Y-%V')]; dt[,.(max.date = max(mydate),  mean.val = mean(.SD[id.sub == "b", val])) , .(id, wk)]`

Comment: @RichardScriven YES, that's just what i want, please write an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: and @akrun,  could you explain why i must create a new "by" column before i use it? does it have anything to do with the internal mechanism of .SD? it would be very nice of both you to explain a litter deeper so that i can avoid such kind of problem next time :)

Comment: It's because the `mydate` becomes inaccessible after we group a modfied version of it.  BTW, why do you need to do it using the `.SD`.

Comment: @akrun, i used to thought `val[id.sub == "b"]` won't work because i cannot subset a vector by another vector. but now i understand that both `val` and `id.sub` are evaluated in the same data.table so the usage is ok. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were looking for `mean.val = mean(val[id.sub == "b"])`.  This is the more standard way to write the subset.  Note that `.()` is the alias for `list()` and can also be used in `by`.

```
dt[, .(
    max.date = max(mydate),
    mean.val = mean(val[id.sub == "b"])),
    by = .(id, wk = format(mydate, "%Y-%V"))
]
#      id      wk   max.date   mean.val
#   1:  5 2009-01 2009-01-04  1.9335678
#   2:  2 2009-01 2009-01-03        NaN
#   3:  4 2009-02 2009-01-10  0.1603871
#   4:  3 2009-02 2009-01-11        NaN
#   5:  1 2009-02 2009-01-08        NaN
#  ---                                 
# 619:  3 2011-51 2011-12-24        NaN
# 620:  1 2011-52 2011-12-28        NaN
# 621:  4 2011-52 2011-12-29 -0.8534370
# 622:  2 2011-52 2011-12-31 -1.2628962
# 623:  3 2012-52 2012-01-01 -1.7779465
```

You can see why your try didn't work if we take a look at all the columns once they're grouped.

```
names(dt[, .SD, by = .(id, wk = format(mydate, "%Y-%V"))])
# [1] "id"     "wk"     "id.sub" "val"
```

As we can see, `mydate` no longer exists.  I'm going to stop there because I'm not confident I could supply a technical explanation as to why.  As akrun notes, it is because it has been modified.

Comment: i see! in the data.table manual it says ".SD is a data.table containing the Subset of x’s Data for each group, excluding
any columns used in by (or keyby)." it seems that i need to go over the manual again. thanks so much.

Comment: what's more, the "standard subset way" in your answer is much much faster than the `.SD` way :)

Comment: Ah, good to hear :)  Happy to help.  Note that this method is just a standard base R vector subset, which is why I think you see a speedup from subsetting the larger table.